# How to change hours format to percentage in a Chart.js pie chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to change the format of data from hours to percentages in the pie chart.
Im pretty new to javascript and this is part of a code im not the author of.

[image]

```
let diagramme = new Chart(canevas, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: axe.composantes.map(c => c.id.toString()),
        datasets: [{
            data: array_lapse, // axe.composantes.map(c => c.duree) // remplacer le format HH:MM -> %
            backgroundColor: couleursDiagramme
        }]
    },
    options: {
rotation: Math.PI,
legend: {
    display: false
},
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        label: (item, data) => formatValToLabel(data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].data[item.index])
    }
},
plugins: {
    datalabels: {
        color: '#FFF',
        font: {
            size: 14,
            weight: 'bold'
        },
        formatter: (val, context) => (val <= 0? '' : formatValToLabel(val))
    }
},
```

}
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the formatValToLabel() function that was formatting the values.